# how to /Tool to analyse below json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

i am trying to read the below json response using jquery and would need to display the "key" and "count" in a HTML table.

Can i paste
the below json in some editor to see what are all the objects, arrays, etc so that i can call the right jquery function?

```
{

      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "2016",
          "count": 196
        },
        {
          "key": "2015",
          "count": 163
        },
        {
          "key": "2014",
          "count": 159
        },
        {
          "key": "2013",
          "count": 157
        },
        {
          "key": "2012",
          "count": 157
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a browser.
2. Open your site.
3. Press F12 dor developer tools (console).
4. Write your object or paste your JSON to console and press ENTER.

[image]

Comment: thanks @hurricane. in F12 Developer Tools, how do i know if something is an object or an array or a key or a value?

Comment: @user3570620 You can see them near to the value. _pieces : Object , _someList : Array, took:2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this editor http://jsoneditoronline.org/ to validate and edit any json object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a foreach and the have it as the value and use the doted notation

```
$.each(document.aggregations.2.buckets, function( key, value ) {
  alert( 'this is count: ' + value.count );
  alert( 'this is key: ' + value.key)
});
```